# outer reuses first element of X instead of doing its job

Tags: r

I have a two argument function that takes as its first input a triple of pairs of numbers in the form "(a, b)(c, d)(e, f)" (as a character string) and as second argument a pair of numbers (also written as a character string of the form "(a, b)") and outputs a logical that states if the pair (the second argument) is one of the three pairs in the triple (the first argument). I actually wrote two versions:

```
version1 <- function(x, y){#x is a triple of pairs, y is a pair
  pairsfromthistriple <- paste(c("", "(", "("), strsplit(x, split = ")(", fixed = T)[[1]], c(")", ")", ""), sep = "")
  y %in% pairsfromthistriple
}

version2 <- function(x, y){#x is triple of pairs, y is pair
  y == substr(x, 1, 6) | y == substr(x, 7, 12) | y == substr(x, 13, 18)
}
```

I want to set this function loose for every triple-of-pairs from a vector of triples an every pair from some vector of pairs using `outer`. For here I'll us the following very short vectors:

```
triples <- c("(1, 2)(3, 4)(5, 6)", "(1, 2)(3, 5)(4, 6)")
names(triples) <- triples
pairs <- c("(5, 6)", "(3, 5)")
names(pairs) <- pairs
```

So here we go:

```
test1 <- outer(X = triples, Y = pairs, FUN = version1)
test2 <- outer(X = triples, Y = pairs, FUN = version2)
```

`test2` evaluates to exactly what you expect, but `test1` gives a non-sensical output:

```
> test1
                   (5, 6) (3, 5)
(1, 2)(3, 4)(5, 6)   TRUE  FALSE
(1, 2)(3, 5)(4, 6)   TRUE  FALSE

> test2
                   (5, 6) (3, 5)
(1, 2)(3, 4)(5, 6)   TRUE  FALSE
(1, 2)(3, 5)(4, 6)  FALSE   TRUE
```

The natural conclusion is that there is an error in `version1`, but it is not as simple as that. 'Manually' computing the terms in the matrix using `version1` gives:

```
> version1(triples[1], pairs[1])
[1] TRUE
> version1(triples[1], pairs[2])
[1] FALSE
> version1(triples[2], pairs[1])
[1] FALSE
> version1(triples[2], pairs[2])
[1] TRUE
```

exactly as it should! So at least part of the fault is with the function `outer`. In fact what happens (in this small example it is not so clear, but this is very visible in larger examples) is that `outer` correctly computes the first row of its output matrix, but then copies this first row over and over to make up the subsequent rows. Obviously this is not what I want. If I only wanted to compute version1(x, y) for all y in some vector but just one single x, I would have used `sapply` rather than `outer`.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note this detail from the documentation for `?outer`:

> `X` and `Y` must be suitable arguments for `FUN`. Each will be extended by rep to length the products of the lengths of `X` and `Y` before `FUN` is called.
>
> `FUN` is called with these two extended vectors as arguments (plus any arguments in `...`). It must be a vectorized function (or the name of one) expecting at least two arguments and returning a value with the same length as the first (and the second).

Your `version1` function is not vectorized properly like `version2` is. You can see this by simply testing it on the original `triples` and `pairs` vectors, which should both match.

```r
version1(triples, pairs)
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE
version2(triples, pairs)
#> (5, 6) (3, 5) 
#>   TRUE   TRUE
```

Your `version1` function seems designed for use with `apply()`, because you retrieve a list from `strsplit()` but then just take the first element. If you want to maintain the approach of splitting the vector, then you would have to use the apply family of functions. Without using them, you are going to expand the `triples` or `x` vector into something much longer than `y` and you can't do element wise comparison.

However, I would just use something very simple. `stringr::str_detect` is already vectorized for `string` and `pattern`, so you can just use that directly.

```r
library(stringr)

outer(X = triples, Y = pairs, FUN = str_detect)
#>                    (5, 6) (3, 5)
#> (1, 2)(3, 4)(5, 6)   TRUE  FALSE
#> (1, 2)(3, 5)(4, 6)  FALSE   TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! At first I didn't understand why you wrote 'because you retrieve a list from strsplit() but then just take the first element'. I thought 'I always take the first element of this stupid list that strsplit outputs, because these lists are always 1 element and it always is the content of that one element that I want - not the list itself'. But then it dawned on me that this is what vectorization is. Apparently if you feed a vector (rather than a single word) into strsplit the output will be a list with more than one element and this is what outer tries to do. (ctd below)

Comment: ... so your comment clarifies more than one mystery for me at the same time. Thanks!